# Can changes made to references returned by Google Mock be reflected in the original value?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Can changes made to references returned by Google Mock be reflected in the original value?

Sample test code (using CppUnit as the unit testing framework):

```
int i = 0;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, GetValue())
    .WillOnce(ReturnRef(i));

...

CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL( 1, i );
```

Sample code:

```
auto x = obj.GetValue();
++x;
```

My testing shows that this doesn't update the value of `i`, but Google's description of `ReturnRef` and `ReturnRefOfCopy` seems to mean that this should work, i.e.

- ReturnRef(variable) - Return a reference to variable.
- ReturnRefOfCopy(value) - Return a reference to a copy of value; the copy lives as long as the action.

Instead it seems like `ReturnRef` also returns the reference to a copy.  Is there some way to get this behaviour using Google Mock?

Comment: `auto& x = obj.GetValue();`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Correct.  Want to make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto` uses the same type deduction rules as templates. In your case `auto x` means the same as a template type parameter.

```
template<typename T>
int function(T t) { 
    T x; // <-- is equivalent to `auto x` outside of a template
};
```

In your example the type is deduced to an `int` rather than `int&` as you were expecting which is why the original value remained the same. You will need to declare the reference explicitly (`auto& x`) in order to modify the original value.